# Send email by codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

I am using codeigniter to send email.

```
function forget_pw() {
    $this->load->library('email');

    $config['smtp_host'] = 'host address';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'username';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('admin@email.com', 'Admin');
    $this->email->to('test@yahoo.com.hk'); 

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

    $this->email->send();

    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

No any error show in console.  But the email didn't send out.

Comment: I feel sorry.  I make a big wrong.  I use the code in my localhost.  But the config is used for my hosting server.  Every thing is ok if it is in my hosting server.

Comment: What local host you use wamp, xampp, lamp etc

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this:

```
public function sendEmail($subject,$message)
{

    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx');
    $this->email->to('xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx');
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo 'Email send.';
    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

And use it like this `$this->sendEmail('Title', 'Message');` Good luck